# Splitting a dataframe by column name indices

Tags: r

This is a variation of an earlier question.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(9*9), ncol=9))
names(df) <- c("c_1", "d_1", "e_1", "a_p", "b_p", "c_p", "1_o1", "2_o1", "3_o1")
```

I want to split the dataframe by the index that is given in the column.names after the underscore "_". (The indices can be any character/number in different lengths; these are just random examples).

```
indx <- gsub(".*_", "", names(df))
```

and name the resulting dataframes accordingly n the end i would like get three dataframes, called:

- df_1
- df_p
- df_o1

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you can split the column names by `indx`, get the subset of data  within the list using `lapply` and `[`, set the names of the list elements using `setNames`, and use `list2env` if you need them as individual datasets (not so recommended as most of the operations can be done within the list and later if you want, it can be saved using `write.table` with `lapply`.

```
 list2env(
     setNames(
       lapply(split(colnames(df), indx), function(x) df[x]),
                paste('df', sort(unique(indx)), sep="_")), 
                                              envir=.GlobalEnv)


head(df_1,2)
#      c_1        d_1        e_1
#1  1.0085829 -0.7219199  0.3502958
#2 -0.9069805 -0.7043354 -1.1974415


head(df_o1,2)
#     1_o1      2_o1       3_o1
#1 0.7924930  0.434396  1.7388130
#2 0.9202404 -2.079311 -0.6567794

head(df_p,2)
#      a_p       b_p        c_p
#1 -0.12392272 -1.183582  0.8176486
#2  0.06330595 -0.659597 -0.6350215
```

Or using `Map`.  This is similar to the above approach ie. split the column names by `indx` and use `[` to extract the columns, and the rest is as above.

```
list2env(setNames(Map(`[` , 
       list(df), split(colnames(df), indx)),
          paste('df',unique(sort(indx)), sep="_")), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

#### Update

You can do:

```
 indx1 <- factor(indx, levels=unique(indx))
 split(colnames(df), indx1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to preserve the order of the dataframes inside the list according to the original input? The vector represented by indx has this order preserved.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this :

```
 invisible(sapply(unique(indx),
                  function(x)                      
                     assign(paste("df",x,sep="_"),
                            df[,grepl(paste0("_",x,"$"),colnames(df))],
                            envir=.GlobalEnv)))

# the code applies to each unique element of indx the assignement (in the global environment) 
# of the columns corresponding to indx in a new data.frame, named according to the indx.
# invisible function avoids that the data.frames are printed on screen.

> ls()
[1] "df"    "df_1"  "df_o1" "df_p"  "indx"  

> df_1[1:3,]
         c_1        d_1        e_1
1  1.8033188  0.5578494  2.2458750
2  1.0095556 -0.4042410 -0.9274981
3  0.7122638  1.4677821  0.7770603

> df_o1[1:3,]
         1_o1        2_o1       3_o1
1 -2.05854176 -0.92394923 -0.4932116
2 -0.05743123 -0.24143979  1.9060076
3  0.68055653 -0.70908036  1.4514368

> df_p[1:3,]
         a_p        b_p        c_p
1 -0.2106823 -0.1170719  2.3205184
2 -0.1826542 -0.5138504  1.9341230
3 -1.0551739 -0.2990706  0.5054421
```